# Максимальное значение

Tags: php, массивы

Нужна помощь.
Есть такой код(опроса):

```
<?php
$fanta = [2, "Вам нравится Фанта"];
$kola = [5, "Вам нравится кола"];
$pepsi = [3, "Вам нравится пепси"];

echo max($fanta[0], $kola[0], $pepsi[0]);
?>
```

У меня получается так, что PHP выводит на экран первое значение, а надо вывести на экран второе значение массива, где первое значение больше остальных, не используя MySQL.

Comment: данный код возвращает значение `5`, так что не ясно, где именно у вас выводится первое значение

Answer (score 1):

```
$fanta = [2, "Вам нравится Фанта"];
$kola = [5, "Вам нравится кола"];
$pepsi = [3, "Вам нравится пепси"];

$x=[$fanta,$kola,$pepsi];
usort($x, function($a, $b){return ($b[0]-$a[0]);});
echo $x[0][1];
```

Comment: Всем благодарен. Очень помогли.

Comment: Собственно вы сделали ровно то, о чем я написал - поменяли модель хранения данных.

Comment: @rjhdby данные так и остались хранится в массивах $fanta,$kola,$pepsi - я проделал с этими массивами некоторые операции после которых массив $x можно и удалить. "Поменять модель хранения данных" это по мне например разбить одну SQL таблицу на несколько, изменить поля/индексы и т.п.

Comment: @Nsk Ваш код работает не с массивами `$fanta,$kola,$pepsi`, а с массивом `$x`. Но это все спор в пользу определений. Главная беда в том, что ваш код наследует основную проблему кода автора вопроса - его придется переписывать сразу же, как появится `$merinda`

Answer (score 0):

В вашем случае только через множество `if - else`.

```
$max = max($fanta[0], $kola[0], $pepsi[0]);
if($fanta[0] == $max) echo $fanta[1]
else if ($kola[0] == $max) echo $kola[1]
else echo $pepsi[1];
```

Это ужасно. Поэтому вам сперва следует переработать вашу модель данных. Например так:

```
$input = [
            ['count' => 2, 'text' => "Фанта"],
            ['count' => 5, 'text' => "кола"],
            ['count' => 3, 'text' => "пепси"]
         ];

usort($input, function (int $a, int $b) { return -($a['count'] <=> $b['count']); });

echo "Вам нравится ".$input[0]['text'];
```

На самом деле вариантов, как организовать данные лучше, чем это сделано у вас - множество.

PS Кола по английски будет `cola`

Comment: однако, сортировка массива для поиска максимального элемента несколько избыточна.

Comment: @teran, дак предложи оптимальный вариант

Answer (score 0):

Не шибко актуально для текущего вопроса, здесь массив содержит только 3 элемента, но тем не менее. Задача поиска максимального значения решается за один проход по массиву, ее сложность `n`, в то время как использование сортировки и взятие первого элемента, как минимум предполагает сложность `nlogn`.

Так что если топикстартеру надо найти текст из массива с максимальным элементом, то как и в других случаях, сначала надо преобразовать три переменные к одному массиву.

```
$data = [$fanta, $kola, $pepsi];
```

Затем, можно, например, сделать числовые значения ключами. Найти  максимум для ключей и вывести соответствующий элемент.

```
$data = array_column($data, 1, 0);
$max  = max(array_keys($data));
$result = $data[$max];
```

либо самый простой способ - использование простого цикла и сравнений:

```
$max = -1; //PHP_INT_MIN или $data[0][0];
$mv  = null;
foreach($data as list($v,$t)){
    if($max < $v){
       $max = $v;
       $mv  = $t;
   }
}
echo $mv;
```

Comment: Я вначале тоже про `array_column` подумал, но решил, что использовать в качестве ключей числа, являющиеся счетчиками - не самый разумный подход.